# Checking if merge request can be merged…

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, gitattributes

On gitlab, I create a merge request where :

- I did a small modification on a small README.md file
- I modified many big json files

  - hierarchy is :

    - /dirA/dirB1/many json files
    - /dirA/dirB1/dirC/many json files
    - /dirA/dirB2/many json files
    - /dirA/dirB2/dirC/many json files
    - /dirA/dirB3/many json files
    - /dirA/dirB3/dirC/many json files
    - /dirA/dirB4/many json files
    - /dirA/dirB4/dirC/many json files
- I add a .gitattributes file with this contents : `*.json -text -merge -diff`

Impossible to merge it, I have a throbber and the message **Checking if merge request can be merged…**

I added the .gitattributes to resolve the problem but nothing changed.

I saw many link about similar problems (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/263390 and https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/229352) but I'm unable to fix (maybe I misunderstood or maybe it isn't linked to my problem).

I don't need to be able to see the changes in my json files (but I need them so I cannot add them in .gitignor).

I ask for help (resolve and understand).

Comment: After a very very long time, it seems ok, the message disappears and I can merge.
I'll give more informations if I see more informations.

Comment: Ok, just very long for gitlab web interface, but finally it's ok